# Android SwipeListView library

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview).

My back view is just a button alling to the right and i can not figure out how to swipe my row list just enough to show the button not all the row.

Now i can just set the offset of the swipe by :

```
my_list_view= (SwipeListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_produse);

my_list_view.setOffsetLeft()
```

But i need a way to swipe the row enough to show the button in the back view

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the xml attribute "swipeOffsetLeft" ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `SwipeListView` before. If you want to show the back view in appropriate width, you need to call `my_list_view.setOffsetLeft();` programmatically. Of course you need to get the width of your `Button` in the back view. Then call `my_list_view.setOffsetLeft();`.

Comment: i try this way... to until now i recive 0dp width for the button in the back. i think because he is not visibile until i swipe